# Message counting in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js, counting

So i want to do a command, where if you enter, it sends a Dino emoji and a "sent by (User)" in a specific channel.
Now i need to know, is it possible to count  every message in this channel and put it in the dino message?

Like the first dino ever would get
"dino #1, sent by @User"

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using the number of messages in the channel for counting. Instead I would use some kind of data storage (JSON file, SQLite, SQL Database, etc) to store the count on the bot side. Fetching all the messages in a channel is a lot of requests to Discord and in some cases could be considered API abuse on Discord's end.